# Precalculus / Algebra - Expression involving $X$ and $Y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$294~x^2y-2772~xy^2+6534~y^3$$

Notice that when we plug $2$ and $1$ into the expression we get the positive number $2166$, and when we plug $2$ and $-1$ we get the negative number $-13,254$.  State all values of $x$ and $y$ for which the above expression is zero or positive.

Explain how you got your answer.

What I tried:

I factored out $6y $ to simplify the expression first. My next step process was to plugin for $(0,y)$ and $(x, 0)$, then set the expression equal to $0$ and that would give me the roots/where the expression is $0$. I'm not sure if what I'm doing is right.

My simpification:

$$6~y(7~x-33~y)^2$$

[image]

Comment: The resolution of your image is quite bad. Would you mind typing it in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)?

Comment: Yeah I just fixed it. I didnt know what MathJax was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want $$6y(7x-33y)^2$$ to be nonnegative. Since the second factor is nonnegative, we only want the first factor to be nonnegative too. Thus, we want $$y\ge 0.$$

Hence, your solution is all real $x,$ and all nonnegative $y.$ That is, the upper half plane.

Comment: Why is the second factor non-negative, what does that exactly mean? And how did you know its non-negative? In your answer, I understood the all non-negative y part, but not how you got the all real x part.

Comment: @ViciCIT The second factor is the *square of a real number.* So provided $x,y$ are real, the second factor can never become negative. In short, if $a$ is real, then $aa$ is never negative -- can you see why?

Comment: But all real numbers means X can be positive or negative. Are you saying X can't be a negative number? Because the question is asking for what values of X and Y the expression is 0 or postitive. But to answer your question, yes I understand now because for the second factor it is being squared, so it will be a positive number in the end.

Comment: @ViciCIT If $x$ is real, then it can be positive, or negative, or zero. It's only that $y$ must not be negative. Then the function is either positive, or vanishes, as wanted.

Comment: Yes, mate. thanks :) I know what you mean now as I can see what you are saying visually. This helped a lot thanks!

Comment: @ViciCIT Glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your factorisation is correct.

Now to have $6y(7x-33y) ≥ 0$, either $6y ≥ 0$ or $(7x-33y)^2 ≥ 0$. Can you continue? Note the special case when $7x-33y=0$.

Comment: For the special case $7x-33y=0$ , I plugged in $0$ for X, and got Y = $0$. Then I plugged in $0$ for Y, and got X = $0$. Does this mean for the value X = $0$ and Y = $ 0$, the expression is $0$?

Comment: Yes, but there's much more to it than that. $7x-33y=0$ is a line, so for all points on that line the expression evaluates to $0$. Your strategy of substituting $x=0$ and $y=0$ does not consider other points when neither $x$ or $y$ are $0$.

Comment: In addition, notice that $a^2 ≥ 0$ for all real numbers $a$.